# Infractions for Radipanel SQL query error

Tags: mysql

this is what im putting in!

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `totalInfractions` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ADD `totalWarnings` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ADD `banned` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
INSERT INTO `menu` (id, text, url, resource, usergroup, protected, weight) VALUES (NULL, 'Add infraction', 'infraction.add', '_res/infraction/add.php', '5', '0', '0');
INSERT INTO `menu` (id, text, url, resource, usergroup, protected, weight) VALUES (NULL, 'Remove infraction', 'infraction.remove', '_res/infraction/remove.php', '5', '0', '0');
INSERT INTO `menu` (id, text, url, resource, usergroup, protected, weight) VALUES (NULL, 'View infraction log', 'infraction.viewLog', '_res/infraction/view.php', '5', '0', '0');
INSERT INTO `menu` (id, text, url, resource, usergroup, protected, weight) VALUES (NULL, 'Clear infraction log', 'infraction.clearLog', '_res/infraction/clear_log.php', '5', '0', '0');
INSERT INTO `menu` (id, text, url, resource, usergroup, protected, weight) VALUES (NULL, 'View my infraction log', 'user.viewMyLog', '_res/infraction/view_mine.php', '1', '0', '0');
CREATE TABLE `infraction_log` ( `id` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `username` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `reason` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `type` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `addrem` VARCHAR( 3 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `issuedby` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `timestamp` TIMESTAMP( 255 ) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

---

This is the error

```
ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD  `totalInfractions` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
ADD  `totalWarnings` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
ADD  `banned` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0';
```

MySQL said:

```
# 1060 - Duplicate column name 'totalInfractions'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

> Duplicate column name 'totalInfractions'

You are trying to add a column to your table with a name that another column already has.